# tinyMCE head styles

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, tinymce

If look the [example of tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) on official website with Firefox you can see the blinking of editor. Only in firefox.
I think it is bacause css files of editor are external and I want to put all css rules in the html file of iframe.

Please help me to find place where I can add inline styles!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the content css, see here for details:

```
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css
```

eg:

```
content_css : "css/custom_content.css"
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. It's works.. May be I asked bad question.. In firefox styles are not applied when iframe loads, they are applied after about half second and I see it. I thought implementing styles in <style> tag in <head> of iframe can fix it but it is not works..

Comment: I suspect that it may just be the delay in loading the stylesheet as Firefox will load the stylesheets/JS and iframe HTML first, then once that is done it will start loading the files linked to from the iframe (ie the stylesheet you want). You could try loading the same stylesheet on the page that contains the iframe as well as the iframe this way it would be in memory by the time it realises the iframe needs it - just an idea though, I've never tried it.